# Context Menu Left Click

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a context menu which used to be a pop up menu. When I first load the program the context menu is empty as the menu items are bound to a list. However if I load the program and right click first the list is fine and then I can go to left click and the list appears. I'll show images to help my description:

**Left click first**

[image]

**Right click first and also left click after**

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why this has happened and how to fix it?

**Edit - Xaml**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="AddNodeTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="buttonAdd">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
                <Canvas>
                    <Image Source="Images/bkg_plus.png" Width="30" Height="30" Panel.ZIndex="5"/>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="LightGray" StrokeDashArray="2 2" Width="120" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type syncfusion:Node}}}">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <TextBlock Text="Add Property" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30 10 0 0" Background="Transparent"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Button.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <Label Content="Add Property"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Button.ToolTip>
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableProperties}">
                        <ContextMenu.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=ToolTips}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=CommandParameter}"/>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon , Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}"/>-->
                            </Style>
                        </ContextMenu.Resources>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**New Result**

Ok so this is now what happens when I do left click first

[image]

**So I have tried using a pop up and have a menu inside this and this is my XAML for the result, the only problem now is I want to change the highlighted background when the mouse is hovered over the "Add Existing Property" does anyone know how to do that and also move the menu over to the right I'll post a picture up to explain**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="AddNodeTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#F7F7F7">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <DrawingBrush Viewport="8,8,8,8" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#F7F7F7">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <StackPanel>
            <ToggleButton Height="30" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource ChromelessToggleButton}" x:Name="toggleButtonAdd" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding ElementName=Popup, Path=IsOpen, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource OppositeBooleanConverter}}">
                <ToggleButton.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <Label Content="Add Property"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </ToggleButton.ToolTip>
            </ToggleButton>
            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButtonAdd}" x:Name="Popup" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Right">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Background="#F7F7F7">
                        <StackPanel Margin="5,10,5,5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Menu Background="#F7F7F7">
                                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Exisiting Properties">
                                <ListBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Margin="5" Padding="4" Width="130"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableProperties}" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
                                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#5194C7"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Upscale Well logs">        
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Upscale well_top attributes">
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Upscale point attributes">
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Calculate">
                                </MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Picture of menu right under the popup rather than to the right like the above pictures I want the background to be blue rather than the gray background as in the picture below**

[image]

Comment: remove your Canvas and check.

Comment: try this style to add image to your button background. <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Image}"/> in resoource add this too <ImageBrush x:Key="Image" ImageSource="../images/Close.png" />

Comment: removing the canvas and adding the style just gives me another black screen :(

Comment: What I'm currently trying to do is use a pop up but have a menu inside of that and see if that works

Comment: I suggest insted of `ListBox` you can use `ContextMenu` and `Style` your `ContextMenu` as given in the answer below, In the Style you can specify what color you need when it shows. Keep in mind that `ContextMenu` shows only when you left click the mouse.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92519/discussion-between-ryan-archibald-and-abin-mathew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a `Context Menu` and `Style` like below, I dont think its necessary to go with `ListBox` inside `MenuItem`

```
 <Button.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableProperties}">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="MenuItem">                            
          <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=ToolTips}"/>
          <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
          <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=CommandParameter}"/>
          <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon , Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}"/>
       </Style>
     </ContextMenu.Resources>                    
   </ContextMenu>
 </Button.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: When I did this my page just went completely black :(, I got no errors nothing just a black screen

Comment: When I try that I get 2 very small rectangles, again right click works perfect and when left click after it it works, do you need a screen shot as to what happens?

Comment: I have no idea why though, tried researching everywhere with no luck as to an explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92405/discussion-between-ryan-archibald-and-abin-mathew).